# How do I investigate a postgresql database which takes forever to return the results from a where clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I restored a database dump from a customer who sent us their production pgsql dump. They use a lot of custom datatypes (for context this is the Hedera cryptocurrency main node dump). While I can easily execute queries such as `select * from table limit 100`, the database takes an abnormally long time to execute queries that use a `where` clause on one of the columns. Even if the column is a built-in datatype, and even if the column is indexed / is the primary key.

How would I go about debugging this? I was wondering if the indices are corrupt, and [wanted to try reindexing the database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html#:%7E:text=One%20way%20to%20do%20this,much%20you%20want%20to%20reconstruct.), but before I do that, is there something else I should look into?

Comment: You can try an [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-explain.html) and see if you get any clues there.  If the EXPLAIN says you're using indexes, then yes, reindexing the database is a possibility.

Comment: Did you run `analyze` after restoring the dump?

Comment: I didn't run analyze. Let me try that and update the question.

Comment: Please show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the slow query.

Answer (score 0):

Custom datatypes cannot be systematically indexed. Worst, PG can index everything but without byte ordered datatype relative to the kind of index, the use of this index will cause some internal infinite loops...